# Only one record returned after union all

Tags: sql, db2, union, db2-400

Using an SQL interface into an AS/400 (iSeries) DB2 database but running into and issue where pallet information **could** be stored in two tables, one for non-allocated stock `(warpall)` and one for allocated stock `(warpalq)`.
I need to return the records from both tables where applicable.

`warpalq` only has a handful of fields in relation to `warpall`
One of the fields I need from `warpall` is also used to join another table, there is no relative field in `warpalq`.

I'm using a `union` to return the data from both tables in one result set, then joining the other tables.

The issue is, when joining the third table `(warcmdt)` on the result set, it has null values / 0 in the `commpm` and `fdsccd` fields as it has no data for that in the respective table.

Is there a way that I can pull in `commpm` & `fdsccd` back into the results set for row 2?
The crosslink would be `pal#pm = pal#pq` so there is a relative link.

Running the SQL below returns this result set.

[image: Undesired result]

```
select 
clntwf, commpm, fdsccd, clsqwf, pal#wf, dtcdpm, clsswf, srb#pm, descsc, 
cor#or  

from
(select substr(warpall.clntpm,1,2) as clntwf, pal#pm as pal#wf, commpm, 
substr(warpall.clsspm,1,2) as clsswf, warpall.clsqpm * 1 as clsqwf, srb#pm, 
dtcdpm, srd#pm 
from warpall

where 
locnpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
and commpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
and clsqpm <> 0
and clntPM <> 'D2'
and pal#pm = '1005609592'

union all

select substr(clntpq,1,2) as clntwf, pal#Pq as pal#wf, '0', 
substr(clsspq,1,2) as clsswf, clsqpq * 1 as clsqwf, '0', '0', '0' 
from warpalq

where 
clsqpq <> 0
and clntPQ <> 'D2'
and pal#pq = '1005609592'

) as t9

left outer join warcmdt as t3
on 
t3.clntcd = t9.clntwf  and t3.commcd = t9.commpm

left join
warclss as t4
on
t4.clsssc = t9.clsswf

left join
warohrh as t5
on
t5.clntor = t9.clntwf 
and t5.srn#or = t9.srd#pm

order by pal#wf asc
```

Comment: Well the queries are completely different than your first example, and have different where clauses and joins, so there's probably no way anyone can make this assessment without sample data.

Comment: Sorry, I just simplified it - ill rewrite with consistency

Comment: No need to apologize. Most likely it's an issue with the join criteria or where clause in the warpalq table. If you put a sample of the records you are expecting it should be pretty easy for someone to spot the problem.

Comment: Just a tip.  On a union all query I add a constant so I can tell where the rows came from select 'mytablea' as t , a, b. c from mytablea union all select 'mytableb' as t , a, b, c from tytableb

Comment: ...`commpm` is explicitly the constant `'0'` for `warpalq` (as a stand-in for null?), which is being used as part of the join condition to `warcmdt`.  Are you sure you have a matching record there?  Like Jacob says, most likely due to join criteria, need example/desired outcome data.

Comment: I've edited the OP with revised syntax and results set.

Comment: Not real sure what you are asking here. It looks like there used to be a question here, but that it morphed into an answer. Questions should stay as questions. If you are able to answer your own question, the answer should be posted as an answer, not edited into the question. That way it has a chance to help others who come by later.

Comment: Once all of the stock is allocated, does the last record come out of `warpall`? So in that case you would have records in `warpalq` but not `warpall`.

Comment: No, it only goes into `warpalq` if it has to split the pallet quantity.

It continues to split until the final allocation of stock on the pallet. It then doesnt split it into `warpalq` and moves to `warpalr` once it's consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a Common Table Expression (CTE) like this:

```
with 
  pal (clntwf, pal#wf, commpm, clsswf, clsqwf, 
       srb#pm, dtcdpm, srd#pm) as (
    select
      substr(warpall.clntpm,1,2) as clntwf, 
      warpall.pal#pm as pal#wf, 
      warpall.commpm, 
      substr(warpall.clsspm,1,2) as clsswf, 
      warpall.clsqpm * 1 as clsqwf, 
      warpall.srb#pm, 
      warpall.dtcdpm, 
      warpall.srd#pm 
    from warpall
    where 
      warpall.locnpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
      and warpall.commpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
      and warpall.clsqpm <> 0
      and warpall.clntPM <> 'D2'
      and warpall.pal#pm = '1005609592'),

   alc (clntwf, pal#wf, commpm, clsswf, clsqwf, 
        srb#pm, dtcdpm, srd#pm) as (
     select 
       substr(warpalq.clntpq,1,2) as clntwf, 
       warpalq.pal#Pq as pal#wf, 
       pal.commpm, 
       substr(warpalq.clsspq,1,2) as clsswf, 
       warpalq.clsqpq * 1 as clsqwf, 
       '0', 
       '0', 
       pal.srd#pm 
     from warpalq
       join pal
         on waarpalq.pal#pq = pal.pal#wf
     where 
       warpalq.clsqpq <> 0
       and warpalq.clntPQ <> 'D2'
       and warpalq.pal#pq = '1005609592')

select 
  clntwf, commpm, fdsccd, clsqwf, pal#wf, dtcdpm, clsswf, srb#pm, descsc, cor#or  
from
  (select *
     from pal
   union all
   select *
     from alc
  ) as t9
  left outer join warcmdt as t3
    on t3.clntcd = t9.clntwf 
      and t3.commcd = t9.commpm
  left join warclss as t4
    on t4.clsssc = t9.clsswf
  left join warohrh as t5
    on t5.clntor = t9.clntwf 
      and t5.srn#or = t9.srd#pm
order by pal#wf asc
```

This lets you reuse the `pal` CTE in multiple places without redefining it. That means you can join it in to the `alc` CTE to get `commpm` which is used later to join `t9` with `warcmdt`. Now you shouldn't get that null. I also brought `srd#pm` into the `alc` CTE from `warpall` because that is used in the join between `t9` and `warohrh`. If this is incorrect, you can replace `pal.srd#pm` with `'0'` in the `alc` CTE.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. There was a typo in one of the warpalq references (waarpalq) but I couldn't edit it due to it being less than 6 characters.